# Set tailwind button default state

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css

Is it possible to have my tailwind button be "focus" on page load?

Below is from tailwind docs.

> default (:default) Style an option, checkbox or radio button that was
> the default value when the page initially loaded using the default
> modifier:

I need the control to be a button specifically.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing Tailwind specific for focusing button in Blazor. Or maybe you are using tailwind ui?

[image]

Simple solution:

```
<button class="bg-red-500 group focus:bg-green-500" type="text" @ref="btnref">
    <span class="group-focus:block hidden">I am focused</span>
    <span class="group-focus:hidden">Not focused</span>
</button>

@code {

    private ElementReference btnref;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await btnref.FocusAsync();
   }
}
```